# gRPC NotImplementedException though method is called

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc

I was trying to play around with protobuf and gRPC in java while following the basic tutorial provided, Although I always tend to create my own scenario and build everything from the ground up. I learn better this way than to copy-paste tutorial code and run it.

I have created the following project (https://github.com/IngoHenkel/protobuf_test) that contains a service class with two services, one synchronous service that simply returns a server info, and an asynchronous service that simulates a longrunning task returning data in a stream.

```
...
service DeepThoughtServices {
    rpc WhoAreYou (google.protobuf.Empty) returns  (WhoAmI) {}
    rpc RequestIntegerTokens(CalculateIntegerTokens) returns (stream IntegerToken) {}
}
...
```

The first service (WhoAreYou) works perfectly fine, but for the other service, I always get a NotImplementedException on the client.
Strangely, the method itsself gets called on the server perfectly fine (which you can see by the logs), but the moment I try to call the "onNext" method to return data, I get the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream was terminated by error, no further calls are allowed
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:502)
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$ServerCallStreamObserverImpl.onNext(ServerCalls.java:374)
    at de.squirrelsquad.tutorials.protobuf.protos.service.DeepThoughtServices.requestIntegerTokens(DeepThoughtServices.java:56)
    at de.squirrelsquad.tutorials.protobuf.protos.service.DeepThoughtServicesGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(DeepThoughtServicesGrpc.java:271)
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:182)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:340)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:866)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

. I first thought that it may have to do with me trying to dispatch the "work" into a background thread and sending the response from there, but even though I now simply send the responses directly within the service method, I still get the error.

Both client and server share the same code base, you can run it by executing mvn package and then run:
`java -jar target/grpc-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -s 8980` to start the server and
`ava -jar target/grpc-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -c localhost:8980` for the client, which will call both methods and then return.

Has anybody got an Idea whats wrong here?

- tried calling the methods directly in the "main" thread (no dispatching)
- played around with package and class names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the beginning of `DeepThoughtServices.requestIntegerTokens()` we see:

```
public void requestIntegerTokens(CalculateIntegerTokens request, StreamObserver<IntegerToken> responseObserver) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    logger.info("Request integer tokens called");
    super.requestIntegerTokens(request, responseObserver);
    responseObserver.onNext(IntegerToken.newBuilder().setValue(1).build());
```

The last line there is the one that throws the `IllegalStateException`.

The problem is the `super.requestIntegerTokens()`. `DeepThoughtServicesImplBase` has default implementations for each method that fail the RPC with UNIMPLEMENTED. This allows adding new methods to the service in the `.proto` without breaking existing code.

To fix your problem, simply remove the call to `super`:

```
public void requestIntegerTokens(CalculateIntegerTokens request, StreamObserver<IntegerToken> responseObserver) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    logger.info("Request integer tokens called");
    // DON'T DELEGATE TO SUPER!
    //super.requestIntegerTokens(request, responseObserver);
    responseObserver.onNext(IntegerToken.newBuilder().setValue(1).build());
```

Comment: How did I not see that. Sometimes you go completely blind. Of course, that was not inteded to be there. Thanks for pointing that out and also for the explaination why that is.